# Converting a range of integers exponentially to another range

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to convert a range of numbers to a another range (in an exponential way). I'm trying to do this in python. I don't have a background in mathematics (nor a formal education in computer science actually), so I'll do my best to explain my question in a clear manner.

Let's say I have the following ranges [A,B]:

```
[-10 , 25]
[-35 , -1]
[0 , 100]
```

I want to normalize them to the following ranges[C,D]:

```
[0 , 3]
[1 , 5]
[0 , 100]
```

I could of course normalize those numbers through this:

```
normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
```

That would give me a (linear) normalized response between 0 and 1.

If I want to get an exponential result, I'd feed the normalized result through a function:

[image]

Now my question:

I want to create a function where I can input both ranges ([A,B] and [C,D]) where at the extremes:

```
A = C
B = D
```

and the results grow exponentially. Again, here my mathematics are lacking. Above image example doesn't give `y = 100` when `x = 100`. So I don't know how to determine the exponential formula considering changing input.

So in short: I want to choose different strengths of exponentials growth while using different variables as input, but always have `y = max_result` when `x = max_input` and `y = min_result` when `x = min_input`.

An example:

```
Input:
# Range of input values
AB = [0,100]
# Range of output values
CD = [0,1000]
# Math function for exponential
formula_input = # Some formula made with range [0,100] on both X and Y

x1 = 10
x2 = 20
x3 = 50
x4 = 90

Output:

formula =  1.072^x 

y1 = 2.004
y2 = 4.017
y3 = 32.34
y4 = 521.832
```

I hope this question is clear enough. Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's begin by writing the most *general* form of an exponential function to be used in this situation:

[image]

Where `a, b, c, d, e` are all constants. Using exponential rules:

- `d` can be separated and combined with `a`:

  [image]
- `c` can be merged with the base `b`:

  [image]

So we have reduced 5 parameters to 3. Now to fit these to the end points; call them `[x1, y1]` and `[x2, y2]`:

[image]

Thus a coordinate in-between is given by:

[image]

`r` is the normalized parameter spanning `[0, 1]`. We have thus condensed the set of parameters to just `B` (plus the end point coordinates).

---

Test with `B = [2, 3, 4, 5]`, endpoints `[1, 2]` and `[3, 10]`:

[image]

Comment: This response is ridiculously good. Thank you so much, I'm going to figure out how to translate the formula to code.

Comment: But what do the variables a, b, c, d, and e that you've used represent?

Comment: @kohloth parameters for the general form of these curves

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you're basically wanting to solve `b^100 = 1000` for `b`.

You can do this using logs:

```
ln(b^100) = ln(1000)
100 ln(b) = ln(1000)
ln(b) = ln(1000) / 100
b = exp(ln(1000) * (1/100))
b = 1000^(1/100)
```

which is approximately 1.07152.

Generalizing this, if you have `[0, A]` to `[0, B]` then `b = B^(1/A)`.

I'm not sure how you are wanting to do ranges that start elsewhere, but however you decide to do it, you should be able to use logarithms to find your solution.